# Python pretty print dictionary of lists, abbreviate long lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pretty-print

I have a dictionary of lists and the lists are quite long. How can I print it in a way that only a few elements of the list show up? Obviously, I can write a custom function for that but is there any built-in way or library that can achieve this? For example when printing large data frames, `pandas` prints it nicely in a short way.

This example better illustrates what I mean:

```
obj = {'key_1': ['EG8XYD9FVN',
  'S2WARDCVAO',
  'J00YCU55DP',
  'R07BUIF2F7',
  'VGPS1JD0UM',
  'WL3TWSDP8E',
  'LD8QY7DMJ3',
  'J36U3Z9KOQ',
  'KU2FUGYB2U',
  'JF3RQ315BY'],
 'key_2': ['162LO154PM',
  '3ROAV881V2',
  'I4T79LP18J',
  'WBD36EM6QL',
  'DEIODVQU46',
  'KWSJA5WDKQ',
  'WX9SVRFO0G',
  '6UN63WU64G',
  '3Z89U7XM60',
  '167CYON6YN']}
```

Desired output: something like this:

```
{'key_1':
    ['EG8XYD9FVN', 'S2WARDCVAO', '...'],
 'key_2':
    ['162LO154PM', '3ROAV881V2', '...']
}
```

Comment: You may also want to take a look at the [`repr` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/repr.html) (`reprlib` in Py3), particularly the `maxlist` setting: `rep = Repr(); rep.maxlist = 3; print rep.repr(obj)` Now combining that with `pprint` is the real challenge.

Comment: Awesome! This is the best answer and exactly what I needed. Could you add as answer? @LukasGraf

Comment: It seems Michael Hoff is already working on a reprlib answer, so I just upvoted that :)

Comment: That doesn't abbreviate! Instantiating the `Repr` class and setting `maxlist` is the key!

Comment: It does, it's just that the default of `maxlist` is `6`, so it's less obvious. Also note that `__builtins__.repr()` is not the same as `repr.repr()` (yeah, the naming really isn't helping in Python 2.x).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it weren't for the pretty printing, the [`reprlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html) module would be the way to go: Safe, elegant and customizable handling of deeply nested and recursive / self-referencing data structures is what it has been made for.

However, it turns out combining the [`reprlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html) and [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) modules isn't trivial, at least I couldn't come up with a clean way without breaking (some) of the pretty printing aspects.

So instead, here's a solution that just subclasses [`PrettyPrinter`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/pprint.py#l84) to crop / abbreviate lists as necessary:

```
from pprint import PrettyPrinter


obj = {
    'key_1': [
        'EG8XYD9FVN', 'S2WARDCVAO', 'J00YCU55DP', 'R07BUIF2F7', 'VGPS1JD0UM',
        'WL3TWSDP8E', 'LD8QY7DMJ3', 'J36U3Z9KOQ', 'KU2FUGYB2U', 'JF3RQ315BY',
    ],
    'key_2': [
        '162LO154PM', '3ROAV881V2', 'I4T79LP18J', 'WBD36EM6QL', 'DEIODVQU46',
        'KWSJA5WDKQ', 'WX9SVRFO0G', '6UN63WU64G', '3Z89U7XM60', '167CYON6YN',
    ],
    # Test case to make sure we didn't break handling of recursive structures
    'key_3': [
        '162LO154PM', '3ROAV881V2', [1, 2, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        'KWSJA5WDKQ', 'WX9SVRFO0G', '6UN63WU64G', '3Z89U7XM60', '167CYON6YN',
    ]
}


class CroppingPrettyPrinter(PrettyPrinter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.maxlist = kwargs.pop('maxlist', 6)
        return PrettyPrinter.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def _format(self, obj, stream, indent, allowance, context, level):
        if isinstance(obj, list):
            # If object is a list, crop a copy of it according to self.maxlist
            # and append an ellipsis
            if len(obj) > self.maxlist:
                cropped_obj = obj[:self.maxlist] + ['...']
                return PrettyPrinter._format(
                    self, cropped_obj, stream, indent,
                    allowance, context, level)

        # Let the original implementation handle anything else
        # Note: No use of super() because PrettyPrinter is an old-style class
        return PrettyPrinter._format(
            self, obj, stream, indent, allowance, context, level)


p = CroppingPrettyPrinter(maxlist=3)
p.pprint(obj)
```

---

Output with `maxlist=3`:

```
{'key_1': ['EG8XYD9FVN', 'S2WARDCVAO', 'J00YCU55DP', '...'],
 'key_2': ['162LO154PM',
           '3ROAV881V2',
           [1, 2, ['a', 'b', 'c'], '...'],
           '...']}
```

Output with `maxlist=5` (triggers splitting the lists on separate lines):

```
{'key_1': ['EG8XYD9FVN',
           'S2WARDCVAO',
           'J00YCU55DP',
           'R07BUIF2F7',
           'VGPS1JD0UM',
           '...'],
 'key_2': ['162LO154PM',
           '3ROAV881V2',
           'I4T79LP18J',
           'WBD36EM6QL',
           'DEIODVQU46',
           '...'],
 'key_3': ['162LO154PM',
           '3ROAV881V2',
           [1, 2, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 3, 4, '...'],
           'KWSJA5WDKQ',
           'WX9SVRFO0G',
           '...']}
```

---

Notes:

- This will create **copies** of lists. Depending on the size of the data structures, this can be very expensive in terms of memory use.
- This only deals with the special case of **lists**. Equivalent behavior would have to be implemented for dicts, tuples, sets, frozensets, ... for this class to be of general use.

Comment: Funny, I had a similar prototype. But I disliked the steps you had to undertake to implement the truncation of dictionaries. +1 for the effort!

Answer (score 12):

You could use [IPython.lib.pretty](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.lib.pretty.html).

```
from IPython.lib.pretty import pprint

> pprint(obj, max_seq_length=5)
{'key_1': ['EG8XYD9FVN',
  'S2WARDCVAO',
  'J00YCU55DP',
  'R07BUIF2F7',
  'VGPS1JD0UM',
  ...],
 'key_2': ['162LO154PM',
  '3ROAV881V2',
  'I4T79LP18J',
  'WBD36EM6QL',
  'DEIODVQU46',
  ...]}

> pprint(dict(map(lambda i: (i, range(i + 5)), range(100))), max_seq_length=10)
{0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 2: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 3: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 4: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 5: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 6: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...],
 7: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...],
 8: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...],
 9: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...],
 ...}
```

---

For older versions of IPython, you might exploit [RepresentationPrinter](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/lib/pretty.py):

```
from IPython.lib.pretty import RepresentationPrinter
import sys

def compact_pprint(obj, max_seq_length=10):
    printer = RepresentationPrinter(sys.stdout)
    printer.max_seq_length = max_seq_length
    printer.pretty(obj)
    printer.flush()
```

Comment: Probably because there are some jerks on the internet

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) module:

```
pprint.pprint(obj)
```

Would output:

```
{'key_1': ['EG8XYD9FVN',
           'S2WARDCVAO',
           'J00YCU55DP',
           'R07BUIF2F7',
           'VGPS1JD0UM',
           'WL3TWSDP8E',
           'LD8QY7DMJ3',
           'J36U3Z9KOQ',
           'KU2FUGYB2U',
           'JF3RQ315BY'],
 'key_2': ['162LO154PM',
           '3ROAV881V2',
           'I4T79LP18J',
           'WBD36EM6QL',
           'DEIODVQU46',
           'KWSJA5WDKQ',
           'WX9SVRFO0G',
           '6UN63WU64G',
           '3Z89U7XM60',
           '167CYON6YN']}
```

And,

```
pprint.pprint(obj,depth=1)
```

Would output:

```
{'key_1': [...], 'key_2': [...]}
```

And,

```
pprint.pprint(obj,compact=True)
```

would output:

```
{'key_1': ['EG8XYD9FVN', 'S2WARDCVAO', 'J00YCU55DP', 'R07BUIF2F7',
           'VGPS1JD0UM', 'WL3TWSDP8E', 'LD8QY7DMJ3', 'J36U3Z9KOQ',
           'KU2FUGYB2U', 'JF3RQ315BY'],
 'key_2': ['162LO154PM', '3ROAV881V2', 'I4T79LP18J', 'WBD36EM6QL',
           'DEIODVQU46', 'KWSJA5WDKQ', 'WX9SVRFO0G', '6UN63WU64G',
           '3Z89U7XM60', '167CYON6YN']}
```

Comment: `pprint.pprint(obj,depth=1)` is the closest thing to what I need. I guess there is not a built in way to print only the first element of the list and then put `...` for the rest. like `{'key_': ['EG8XYD9FVN', ...]`

Answer (score 3):

Use [reprlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html). The formatting is not that pretty, but it actually abbreviates.

```
> import repr
> repr.repr(map(lambda _: range(100000), range(10)))
'[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...], ...]'
> repr.repr(dict(map(lambda i: (i, range(100000)), range(10))))
'{0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...], 1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...], 2: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...], 3: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...], ...}'
```

Comment: Yep. The "abbreviation" part, or dealing with recursive / self referencing structures is exactly what it was made for. Unfortunately it's not obvious how to combine it with pretty printing (newlines, indentation, ...).

Answer (score 2):

This recursive function I wrote does something you're asking for.. You can choose the indentation you want too

```
def pretty(d, indent=0):
    for key in sorted(d.keys()):
        print '\t' * indent + str(key)
        if isinstance(d[key], dict):
            pretty(d[key], indent+1)
        else:
            print '\t' * (indent+1) + str(d[key])
```

The output of your dictionary is:

```
key_1
    ['EG8XYD9FVN', 'S2WARDCVAO', 'J00YCU55DP', 'R07BUIF2F7', 'VGPS1JD0UM', 'WL3TWSDP8E', 'LD8QY7DMJ3', 'J36U3Z9KOQ', 'KU2FUGYB2U', 'JF3RQ315BY']
key_2
    ['162LO154PM', '3ROAV881V2', 'I4T79LP18J', 'WBD36EM6QL', 'DEIODVQU46', 'KWSJA5WDKQ', 'WX9SVRFO0G', '6UN63WU64G', '3Z89U7XM60', '167CYON6YN']
```

Comment: If you change the last line to `print '\t' * (indent+1) + str(d[key][:2]) + '...'` it would be similar to what I mean. Don't want the entire list

Comment: Oh gotcha, I thought you wrote ... because you didn't wanna write the whole thing out again, my misunderstanding!