# Python dictionary change

Tags: python, dictionary

So I was wondering if there is a way to print out a dictionary without showing the {} or the ''/"". I have a dictionary that looks like, (this is the rough output):

```
{
  'Douglas Adams': {"The Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy"},
  'Dan Brown': {'The Da Vinci Code'},
  'F. Scott Fitzgerald': {'The Great Gatsby'},
  'Cornelia Funke': {'Inkheart'}, 
  'William Goldman': {'The Princess Bride'},
  'Harper Lee': {'To Kill a Mockingbird'},
  'C S Lewis': {'The Lion the Witch and the Wardrobe'},
  'Gary Paulsen': {'Hatchet'},
  'Jodi Picoult': {"My Sister's Keeper"},
  'Philip Pullman': {'The Golden Compass'},
  'J.K. Rowling': {'Harry Potter Series'},
  'Louis Sachar': {'Holes'}
}
```

I would like it to look more like, (output):

```
Douglas Adams, The Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy
Dan Brown, The Da Vinci Code
F. Scott Fitzgerald, The Great Gatsby
Cornelia Funke, Inkheart
```

(I shorted it to save some space :))

I also I have some instances where I run my code and I get some dictionary outputs like:

```
{'J R R Tolkien': {'The Hobbit', 'The Lord of The Rings'}
```

how would I allow it to say:

```
J R R Tolkien , The Hobbit
J R R Tolkien , The Lord of The Rings
```

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to print the dictionary yourself. Iterate over the key/value pairs, and print a line for each one. On each line, start with the author (the key), followed by a comma-separated list of the titles (the values, using something like `", ".join(value)`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pretty print dictionary of lists, abbreviate long lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533282/python-pretty-print-dictionary-of-lists-abbreviate-long-lists)

Answer (score 3):

I think you would need to iterate the items of the dictionary and print them that way, for example (*edited to account for when v is a list or set*):

```
def printDict(books):
    for k, v in books.items():
        if(type(v) != str):
            for vs in v:
                print(f"{k} , {vs} \n")
        else:
            print(f"{k} , {v} \n")
    return None
```

So if v (the value) is not a string, instead its a list or set etc, it will try iterate over the strings in v

Comment: It's not unnecessary, the else makes sure that the code accomplishes its task even if it's provided with a single string and not an iterable type. It's a safety measure.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested loops to go through the items in the dictionary, and within each item, through titles. Use [f-strings or formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) to print:

```
for author, titles in books.items():
    for title in titles:
        print(f'{author}, {title}')
```